# Help in a stars and bars problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am solving a combinatorics task that goes something like this

$a_0$ + $a_1$ + $a_2$ ..... + $a_{n-1}$ = $k$

and there is an upper bound on each term $a_i$ as (0<=$a_i$<=i)

I need to find the parity of the solution.

#### My Work

I have written a code that evaluated the sum ,for example like

$a_0$ + $a_1$ + $a_2$ + $a_3$ = 3

the answer is even as there are 6 solutions

```
0 0 0 3
0 0 1 2
0 0 2 1
0 1 0 2
0 1 1 1
0 1 2 0
```

but i used a recursive approach and it has a time complexity of $2^n$

also i have only been asked the parity, so maybe there is some catch there.

Please, help. I need to find some formula or some algorithm that has a complexity of $O(sqrt(n))$ or below

Comment: I am very curious how to do this as well, but MSE does not like to help with ongoing coding contests: https://www.codechef.com/OCT20A/problems/INVSMOD2

Comment: [OEIS A008302](https://oeis.org/A008302) suggests to me that $O(n^2)$ should be possible